# Asterisk: don't wait for AGI script (bash) to finish before continuing in dialplan

Tags: bash, asterisk, agi

I have an Asterisk dialplan that executes a bash script that matches the callerID with a database to geolocate the caller (by matching country and area codes). Since the database is quite large (global scale), it takes up to 15 seconds to finish.

I need to run this script immediately after answering the call (in case the user hangs up before the call is finished), but don't want the user to wait for the script execution. The return values should ideally be processed at the end of the dialplan just before the hangup.

Q1: I found http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+AGI#Forkandcontinuedialplan which deals with my problem in regards to perl scripts. How do i accomplish the same in bash? I know I can send any bash script to the background by adding a "&" at the end, but I'm clueless how to do that in the dialplan / when using AGI scripts.

Q2: How can I process the values even if the user hung up before / the dialplan "exited non-zero"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use fastagi interface. Or fire UserEvent with AMI listener.

AGI is not  designed to work like you want, so it will not work.

Sure you can use nohup command to get immortal bash script, but that is not the way it have be.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Would using fastAGI be better because I can distribute load to other machines or would it also make it possible to continue in the dialplan while the script is running and then process return values at a later point?

Comment: Fastagi is external TCP server. You can put message inside server or just do whatever u want. Connect will be closed, but thread usualy not closed(depend of your server realization). For example if user perl Asterisk::FastAGI, you can just map function to dialplan, after that refer same call to other function when needed etc. You can use AMI to do call action(communication from fastagi server to asterisk) or you can ask from asterisk dialplan enother action, whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm pretty new to all this, so this helps a lot. Will try to implement this over the next few days, but i'll mark the question as solved anyway. Thanks!